# Number of correct answers in multiple choice test

Tags: problem-solving, word-problem

I have the following problem solving question:

> In a multiple choice test of 25 questions, four marks are given for each correct answer and two marks are deducted for each wrong answer. One mark is deducted for any question which is not attempted. James scores 55 marks and wants to know how many questions he got right. He can't remember how many questions he did not attempt, but he doesn't think it was very many. How many questions did James get right?

I've worked out that he gained $2.2$ marks per question on average and lost $1.8$ marks per question on average (because $55/25$ is $2.2$ and $4-2.2$ is $1.8$).

I've also stated that $2x+y=45$, where $x$ is the number of questions he got wrong and $y$ is the number of questions he didn't answer. Consequently, $100-(2x+y)=55$.

Additionally, I know that getting every question wrong would result in $-50$ total marks, not answering any question would result in $-25$, and answering all correctly would result in $100$.

However, I don't know what to do with any of this information.

Comment: wont it be $6x+5y=45$ as not only is his marks getting deducted but he is also not getting the 4 marks for the question

Comment: Find the only pair of integers in @avz2611's equation (this shouldn't be too difficult). Then deduce $z$ = number of questions James got right.

Comment: Why is it 6 and 5?

Comment: Your $100-(2x+y)=55$ is not  correct.  He got $25-x-y$ questions right, so scored $4(25-x-y)$ for those.  The equation is then $4(25-x-y)-2x-y=55$.  IF you start from $100$ each wrong answer costs $6$, the $4$ you didn't get for answering right and the $2$ you lose for answering wrong and each non answer costs $5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information about the test and knowledge that he earned 55 points, we have
$$
55 = 4(25-y-x)-2x-y=100-4y-4x-2x-y=100-6x-5y
$$
or equivalently,
$$
6x+5y=45.
$$
We know that $y$ and $x$ must each be nonnegative integers, and that $y$ must be "small".
Setting $y=0$, $y=1$, and $y=2$ gives $x=45/6$, $x=40/6$, and $x=35/6$ respectively, which aren't valid because these are integer values. However setting $y=3$ yields
$x=30/6=5$.

Thus James answered 22 questions, got 5 wrong, and 17 correct. To check our answer, observe that
$$4(17)-3-2(5)=68-3-10=55.$$
The only other possible answer is to have $y=9$ and $x=0$, which says that James answered 16 questions, got 0 wrong, and 16 correct.

Answer (score 1):

Let the number of correct answers be $C$, number of wrong answers be $W$, and number of unattempted answers be $N$.

$$C+W+N=25$$
$$4C-2W-N=55$$

Eliminating $C$,
$$6W+5N=45$$

Therefore,
$$W=0, N=9$$
or
$$W=5, N=3$$

If you consider $9$ as many, then

$$C=17, W=5, N=3$$

Comment: Min $N$ seems reasonable, or if you assume $W>0$. +1

Answer (score 0):

Number of correct answers: $t$

Number of false answers: $ f$

Number of questions not answered:$n$

$4t - 2f - n= 55$.

$t+f+n=25.$

Adding : $5t -f =80.$

$t=(80+f)/5;$

Trial $f=0,$  $f=5$, $f=10$, etc.

You get :

1)$f=0; t=16; n=9.$

2)$f= 5 ; t=17: n=3.$

$f=10 ; t=18;$  no solution.

Choose 2).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you answer all 25 questions correct. You will get 100 marks. But you only have 55. The difference is 45 marks. For every wrong answer, you not only lose 4 marks but also deduct extra 1 marks. Which means for every wrong answer you lose 5 marks. 45 / 5 = 9. You answer 9 questions wrong and 16 correct.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What is the point of poting this as an answer to a 2 years old question with an accepted answer?